# Onclick show/hide image. No Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, hide, show

We have developers working on our website and they have given me the run around. We use fancybox for product images and have the following in HTML content area. If i click on one of the links and see an image. Javascript will not work in the content area and the developers say it will be alot of money for a work around.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="promo-top">
<ul>
<li><a title="See Details" href="{{store url=''}}"><strong>Free Shipping</strong> ~ On&nbsp;Orders Over $150</a></li>
<li><a title="See Details" href="{{store url=''}}"><strong>Promo 2</strong> ~ TBA</a></li>
<li><a title="See Details" href="{{store url=''}}"><strong>Promo 3</strong> ~&nbsp;TBA</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies Rony, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of click you can use CSS pseudoclass :hover to display image near link, when hover link. Or you can use target="_blank" for link to open images in new window.

Comment: Thanks SLonoed! I will give that a go. I have not seen any of the back end code. Do you think it is strange that we have Ajax and JavaScript working on other areas of the site but can't get the functionality here? Thanks in advance